# Reasons why training error can go up after more training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In the context of deep-learning, I understand why the test or validation error can go up with more training: this is the result of overfitting.

I also can think of one reason why even the training error would go up after more training: if the learning rate is too big, then the parameter will "jump" too far on the loss function: Even though the gradient is in direction $x$, the parameter update will be too big so that it "goes over" the minimum.

But is this the only reason that training error can go down after more training?

**What are all the reasons that training error can go down after more training?**